# How to make a scrolling website mobile friendly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin

I have made this [website](http://stuartjones.me/OldWebsite/) it works fine on Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome.
But when I try and access it through my mobile it seems to get rid of all the margins which messed up the layout of the website

This is what it looks like on the browsers (what I want it to look like on the phone or at least similar with some sort of margin!):

[image: View in computer browsers]

This is the view I get when using my Samsung Galaxy to view the website (As you can see it has removed the side margins):

[image: View in phone browsers]

here is my css code for the content area (the shaded rectangle):

```
.content {
    width:800px;
    height:auto;
    margin:6% auto;    //I think it is to do with this
    position:relative;
    background-color:black;
    opacity: 0.75;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    padding:25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any idea how to sort this out? I have tried changing it to px but that makes the problem even worse.

Comment: +1 for phone screenshot

Comment: Maybe you should use JQuery mobile for this.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com  There are some impressive sites built with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be that your content is fixed at 800px so if your phones screen is approx 800px there wont be any space left on the sides.

You should take a look at media queries for css and maybe have a different content width for phones, so there will still be margin left on the left and right.

Example

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.content {
width:500px;
margin: 6% auto;
}

}
```

Comment: ahh I see what you mean! would changing it from px to %'s work?

Answer (score 2):

as the above answer mentions - you need to use @media

Meida queries are the way - here are some sizes
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

This is a viewport issue. You do not need to change your CSS. Read up on viewports here:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/